# What if the question is answered but the poster of question reedited

Tags: discussion

After the poster re-edited his question. sometimes make the answers are not coincident with question. How to deal with this kind of problem. thanks.

Comment: hmm.. chameleon question is not a good search term.. I searched google "question edited after posting answer", but that question doesn't showed up in first or second page. So every chance that duplicates will come

Comment: @joe Do you have a specific instance? If the edit is really inappropriate, it might have to be rolled back.

Comment: @Bart How do we get edit rolled back .. there are some issues I faced helping someone.

Comment: @Shail If you go to the revision history, each previous revision will have a "rollback" link. Clicking that will roll the post back to that particular revision. Be careful though. Rolling back should only ever be done in extreme cases. It is not a weapon for personal battles.

Comment: @Bart Sure I understand that ..

Comment: @Bart I flagged a question which was of type "I want to create" no code nothing except the demand to create the whole stuff . The flag was accepted as helpful but it didnt got closed .. Dont you think these type of questions by members with reputation will encourage new users to post in the similar fashion and start a wrong trend .

Comment: @Shail The comments here might not be the best place to discuss that. And without the exact question I can only assume that the handling moderator saw a reason for the question to remain. From your description it sounds like it should be closed, but that's impossible to judge for me. That said, these comments are not the place to discuss it. If you are unclear on the situation, see if it has been discussed on Meta before. If you don't find anything, by all means ask.

Comment: @Bart please review it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239785/how-to-generate-css-with-loop-in-less/15242223#15242223  this question is through (created-answered-edited-answered by myself-closed-reopened). I don't what can we do now ....